# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined although everything works

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transforms

I am making a carousel slider and, although it works as it should, i get this error: `something.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

The script that runs this code is set to run after the page has loaded using the following function

```
function ready(callback){
  // in case the document is already rendered
  if (document.readyState!='loading') callback();
  // modern browsers
  else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
  // IE <= 8
  else document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){
      if (document.readyState=='complete') callback();
  });
}
```

The carousel looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjT3C.png).

The structure of the HTML is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfeel.png).

I have a script that generate the `li` objects with the necessary elements within.

```
var listElement = document.createElement("li");
var textElement = document.createElement("p");
var linkElement = document.createElement("a");
linkElement.setAttribute("href","/web/window/window.html");
var textContent = document.createTextNode(data.results[i].original_title);
textElement.appendChild(textContent);
listElement.setAttribute("class", "card");
listElement.setAttribute("data-target", "card")
var imgElement = document.createElement("IMG");
var imgPath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780"+data.results[i].poster_path;
imgElement.setAttribute("src",imgPath)
linkElement.appendChild(imgElement);
listElement.appendChild(linkElement);
listElement.appendChild(textElement);
document.getElementById("ulMV").appendChild(listElement);
```

And finally the script that runs the carousel which is place in the head tag.

```
ready(function(){
  const carousel = document.querySelector("[data-target='carousel']");
  const card = carousel.getElementsByClassName("card");
  console.log(card)
  const leftButton = document.querySelector("[data-action='slideLeft']");
  const rightButton = document.querySelector("[data-action='slideRight']");


  let offset = 0;

  leftButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (offset !== 0) {
      offset += 234;
      for(var x = 0;x<=card.length;x++){
        card[x].style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
      }
    }
  })

  rightButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    offset -= 234;
    for(var x = 0;x<=card.length;x++){
      card[x].style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
    }

  })
})
```

This uses the `ready` function mentioned in the first place.

Everything works how it should but the error keeps appearing every time i press any of the two buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var x = 0;x<=card.length;x++){
```

Probably this line is a problem (of course every occurrence).
Arrays are zero-indexed. `length` property returns just a number of items. If you think about amount of elements it may be from 1 to `<number_of_elements>`. But in loop context is from 0 to `<number of elements> - 1`.

Let's say you have 4 elements.

```
el1
el2
el3
el4
```

Number of els: 4
Your loop executes from 0 until `card.length` is higher or equal. So it executes for 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. It executes 5 times, but you have only 4 elements. Change it just to `x < card.length` and it will work. Then if it hit `i = 4` it will not execute because `4 < 4` is false.

Comment: Yes this was the problem! Thank you so much! Have a good day sir!